# "Нефть, которой избегают" или "которую"?

Tags: местоимения

Сosider this sentence "Нефтеперерабатывающие заводы в этих странах раскупают дешевую российскую нефть, которой избегает большинство западных покупателей."

Shouldn't the part "нефть, которой избегают" be "нефть, которую избегают"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are special dictionaries of collocations (Словарь сочетаемости русского языка/ Денисов, Морковкин.

They show which case is used after a certain verb. Let us have a look.

ИЗБЕГ АТЬ, избегаю, избегаешь, избегают, несов.; избежать,
избегу, избежишь, избегут, сов.
.1. Сторониться **кого-чего-л.**: намеренно уклоняться.
Избегать кого: (о человеке) ~ отца, соседа, знакомых, друг
друга, его её. меня, Мухина ...; избегать чего: ~ чьего-л. общества,
какого-л. разговора, расспросов, объяснений, встречи, взгляда,
резких движений, каких-л. (непонятных ...) выражений, каких-л.
(бранных ...) слов ...; (с неопр ф>) ~ говорить о ком чём-л., бывать
где-л., встречаться с кем-л., смотреть куда-л. или на кого что-л. ...
Избегать как: ~ явно, открыто, старательно, напрасно ...
Стать, перестать, стараться ... избегать кого чего-л

So genetive case is normally used after this veb.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/types/17_6

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that the word "избегает" here is related to "большинство" rather than "нефть": majority is avoiding to by Russian oil - "большинство избегает...". However the whole sentence isn't built very well, I think somewhat better will be "Нефтеперерабатывающие заводы в этих странах раскупают дешевую российскую нефть, **чего** избегает большинство западных покупателей." Majority isn't avoiding the oil itself, majority is avoiding **to buy** Russian oil.

On the other hand the following sentence sounds ok to me: "Нефтеперерабатывающие заводы в этих странах раскупают дешевую российскую нефть, приобретать которую избегает большинство западных покупателей." See the difference?